# How to correctly delete a folder that is part of TFS project's branch?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015

Using VS 2015 and TFS 2013.
Needed to delete and recreate the Dev branch. I deleted it from Source Control Explorer in VS, checked in pending changes and the branch disappeared.

But the branch folder was still there in the workspace (local disk).

I deleted that from disk assuming since TFS deleted it from source control and I don't need it, it should be safe to delete.

Now when I recreated the Dev branch as child of Main branch, and try to merge Main to Dev, I get conflicts for every single file and folder in Main, saying item was removed from target branch. Why is TFS complaining? Why is there no way to resolve this with one click instead of individually clicking "use source version" button? Or, what am I doing wrong? :)

Comment: Instead of deleting the branch I probably would have checked everything out and overwrote the files in the dev branch and checked it in.  This way only files with differences would have been checked in.  Also you would of had to manually add any new files.  If you delete or rename a branch this sort of behavior will happen above.

Comment: Tested with VS2015 Update1 + TFS2013 Update5, when delete a branch and check in the pending changes, the branch folder will disappear from my workspace. Recreate branch doesn't have any issue. How to reproduce your issue?

Comment: I'm also on VS2015 update 1 but TFS2013 update 3. Problem got resolved after restarting computer. Suspecting it's something related to cache like @Caludius mentions below. Also mine was a MVC5 solution with several nuget packages. Not sure if that makes any difference - maybe due to any locks different processes put on files.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is `workspace` location on you local stored in `source control`.

Easiest solution go to: `File>>Source Control>>Advanced>>Workspaces>>Edit`

Remove the `workspace` giving you trouble.(if you have any checked out files checked them in first)

Delete local files. Go to source control and mapped to different location.

You can remap it to same location if you restart visual studio and have a 
`luck`.

Other way is to clear `tfs cache`.

```
%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache
```

Number may be different.